# For loop to read a CVE list and compare

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to loop through a list of CVE's, compare against rpm -qa --changelog, and output the RPM name, and CVE grep output but just can't get there.

The list is in a column format.

I'd like the output to be like:
RPM : CVE output

```
rpm -q $RPM --changelog|grep $CVE
```

where $RPM comes from rpm -qa, and $CVE comes from cat CVE.list

Comment: How come RPM comes from `rpm -qa` when it's between `rpm -qa` and `--changelog`? Also how your tokens in CVE.list separated? By line or by spaces?

Answer (score 1):

The following isn't a slick one-liner but it works.   --John Hall

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# Show which installed RPM's contain specified CVE's.
#
echo "\
CVE-2011-3348
CVE-2012-0031
" | \
while read CVE
do
     case $CVE in
         "") break ;;
     esac
     echo; echo "Processing [$CVE] ... "
     rpm -qa | \
     while read RPM
     do
          rpm -q --changelog $RPM | grep $CVE > /dev/null
          case $? in
              0) echo "RPM: $RPM "
                 rpm -q --changelog $RPM | grep $CVE
              ;;
          esac
     done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
rpmout=$(rpm -q $RPM --changelog)
for vuln in $(cat "$CVE")
do
    cvegrep=$( rpm -q "$RPM" --changelog | grep "$vuln")
    echo -en "$rpmout : $cvegrep\n"
done
```

edit: edited to account for specific output needs.  This may need further edits depening on exactly what the CVE file formatting is like, and what the output of the rpm command is like.

Comment: $(cat "$CVE") could be simplified as $(<"$CVE").

Comment: Unfortunately this does not provide me with a clean output of the RPM name followed by the output of the changelog where the CVE is patched.

Comment: Edited the initial RPM query, as to get the changelog from the RPM it's, rpm -q $RPM --changelog. Then to find the specific CVE you follow with |grep $CVE

My hope is to have an output like:
openssh : Fixed CVE-1234-5678

Comment: so then the line needs to be something like
     rpm -q $RPM --changelog &&  rpm -q $RPM --changelog | grep "$CVE"

Comment: or better yet, assign each to their own variables: 
    rpmout=$(rpm -q $RPM --changelog)
    cvegrep=$( rpm -q $RPM --changelog | grep "$CVE")
    echo -en "$rpmout : $cvegrep\n"